# Get matlab -batch return values when called via commend line

Tags: python, matlab, command-line-interface

I wonder if there is an easy way to get return values of a Matlab (2021b) function when I call the function via command prompt.

So here is what I have to call:

```
matlab -batch "[RESULT, DESCRIPTION] = myFunction(someVariables)"
```

A little more background information:

I'm calling this function from my Python (3.6) based CI framework from a Windows VM (Windows 10). Both, `RESULT` and `DESCRIPTION` yield important information about the success of tests executed via myFunction().

I know about the possibility to add `-logfile`, but this logs all the information that is printed to console (stdout, stderror), and not only the return variables I need to know.

Comment: Did you tried `matlab` module? [Call MATLAB Functions from Python](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-python.html)

Comment: Not yet, I hoped to get around without introducing new 'dependencies'. The CI team does not like that very much ^^